# What is the best method to get multiple level nested ServletRequest of particular type from ServletRequestWrapper?

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest

I have `ServletRequest` that is wrapped multiple times via `javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper#ServletRequestWrapper`

I have also some method where the incoming parameter is `HttpServletRequest` which is top level Wrapper of `ServletRequest`.

There is convenient method to check if this incoming `ServletRequest` is wrapped by some particular `ServletRequestWrapper` - `javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper#isWrapperFor(java.lang.Class)`

My question is if there exists some method(In some java lib) that allows getting this particular `ServletRequestWrapper` from incoming `HttpServletRequest`

The method that does similar stuff:

```
    public <T extends HttpServletRequestWrapper> Optional<T> findWrapper(
            HttpServletRequest request, Class<T> type) {
        ServletRequest servletRequest = request;
        HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapper;
        while (servletRequest instanceof HttpServletRequestWrapper) {
            wrapper = (HttpServletRequestWrapper) servletRequest;
            if (type.isAssignableFrom(wrapper.getClass())) {
                return Optional.of((T) wrapper);
            } else {
                servletRequest = wrapper.getRequest();
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

Comment: that's cool, what is this used for exactly?

Comment: I use this method to unwrap `ServletRequest` to object of some type and call some method on it